# A question about free product $\mathbb{Z_{2}}*\mathbb{Z_{2}}*\mathbb{Z_{2}}$

Tags: group-theory, free-groups

I want to use some examples to comprehension the definition of free product. Let $\mathbb{Z_{2}}$ be the integers $\{o, ...,m-1\}$ with addition modulo $m$ as the group operation and $\Gamma=\mathbb{Z_{2}}*\mathbb{Z_{2}}*\mathbb{Z_{2}}$ be the 3-fold free product of $\mathbb{Z_{2}}$. What are the reduced words in $\Gamma$?

I use $a, b, c$ to denote the non-identity element in the first $\mathbb{Z_{2}}$, the second $\mathbb{Z_{2}}$ and the third $\mathbb{Z_{2}}$ (Indeed, $a=b=c=1\in \mathbb{Z_{2}}$). And I think the reduced word is that it does not contain the same letter in two neighboring positions. Right？ And the $\{a, b, c\}$ are the generators of $\mathbb{Z_{2}}*\mathbb{Z_{2}}*\mathbb{Z_{2}}$, right?

Comment: ...and what do you do with the zero element in each copy of $\;\Bbb Z_2\;$ ? Not to mention that we usually use multiplicative operation in free products as they're not abelian unless all but one of the factors are trivial and the remaining one is abelian. I think it'd be clearer, and better, to take the multiplicative group $\;C_2:=\{1,c\}\;$ to form the three-fold free product.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let us set $G_i$ for the $i$-th copy of $\mathbb{Z}_2$ ($i=1,2,3$).

The words in $\Gamma$ are (by definition) :

$$a_1...a_r\text{ where } a_k\in G_1\cup G_2\cup G_3 $$

Now if some $a_k$ is $0$ in $G_i$ then you can delete it (via reduction) so in fact if we set :

$$G_i:=\{0_i,1_i\}$$

A reduced word should be of this form :

$$a_1...a_r\text{ where } a_k=1_i \text{ with }i=1\text{, }2 \text{ or } 3 $$

Finally to make sure that it is indeed a reduced word you must add the following condition :

$$\text{ If } a_k=1_i\text{ and } a_{k+1}=1_j\text{ then } i\neq j $$

This means that two adjacent letters cannot be in the same copy of $\mathbb{Z}_2$ (the same thing you said).

Finally :

$$\Gamma=\{\epsilon\}\cup\{1_{i_1}1_{i_2}...1_{i_k}|i_l\neq i_{l+1}\}$$

In my notation we see that $1_1$, $1_2$ and $1_3$ generate $\Gamma$ so indeed, with your notation $\{a,b,c\}$ is a generating set of $\Gamma$.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer :)